# Mapbox Android - change user location icon

Tags: location, marker, mapbox-android

I'm doing the following as suggested by mapbox documentation in order to replace the location icon with a custom one. I run this after the style json is loaded.

It doesn't work for me at all. First of all the location icon doesn't even change. Also the user position updates are no longer shown. Meaning that even though I send new positions to Mapbox the location icon stays still. Has anyone else encountered this? I have exhausted all attempts I can think of.

```
LocationComponentOptions customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
.elevation(5)
.accuracyAlpha(.6f)
.accuracyColor(Color.RED)
.foregroundDrawable(R.drawable.android_custom_location_icon)
.build();
 
// Get an instance of the component
locationComponent = mapboxMap.getLocationComponent();
 
LocationComponentActivationOptions locationComponentActivationOptions =
LocationComponentActivationOptions.builder(this, loadedMapStyle)
.locationComponentOptions(customLocationComponentOptions)
.build();
 
// Activate with options
locationComponent.activateLocationComponent(locationComponentActivationOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try adding `locationComponent.setLocationComponentEnabled(true);` at the end?

Work off of what's in the `enableLocationComponent()` method and when `enableLocationComponent ()` is run, at https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/location-component-options

> even though I send new positions to Mapbox

Can you post code to show how you're doing this?